# Is there a linear isometry between $(\Bbb R^N, \left \| \cdot \right \|_{1} )$ and $(\Bbb R^N, \left \| \cdot \right \|_{\infty} )$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

An apology if I did not specify it well. I want to find a function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N}, x \rightarrow \varphi \left(x \right)$ that is bijective , linear and preserving the norm, ie $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, \left \| x \right \|_{1} = \left \| \varphi \left ( x \right) \right \|_{\infty}.$

I have dealt with some functions but I can not find a convenient one.

I'm sorry, I mean isomorphic as topological spaces with the metrics there, but the isomorphism does not come with the identity, because it does not preserve the norm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: They're not isomorphic as normed spaces. What you can say is that the norms are equivalent, in the sense they define the same topology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because it is unclear what you are asking. Perhaps you mean "isomorpic as topological spaces with the two metrics shown", where the isomorphism is the identity. Please edit the question to tell us if that is what you are asking, or if it's something else. You might want to search for "equivalent norms". Please don't reply to this comment.

Comment: Only for $N=1$ and $N=2$ does there exist an isometric isomorphism between the two spaces.

Comment: You can help me support that fact, because I started to review and I'm supposed to prove that they are equivalent, which does not make much of a problem for me, but rather on how I show that it does not generate bijection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Batomintovski states, $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ are isometrically isomorphic if and only if $n \in \{1,2\}$.

For $n = 1$ the spaces are the same.

For $n=2$ check that the isometrical isomorphism $T : (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_\infty) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_1)$ is given by

$$T(x,y) = \frac12 (x+y, x-y)$$

Indeed $$\|T(x,y)\|_1 =  \frac{|x-y| + |x+y|}{2} = \max\{|x|,|y| \} = \|(x,y)\|_\infty$$

Bijectivity follows from injectivity because of equality of dimensions.

For $n \ge 3$ count the number of [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) on the unit ball in the two spaces.

For $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ the extreme points are of the form $(\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n)$ with $\varepsilon_i \in \{-1,1\}$. Hence there are $2^n$ extreme points.

For $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_1)$ the extreme points are 
$$(\pm 1, 0, 0,\ldots, 0), (0,\pm 1,0, \ldots, 0), \ldots, (0,\ldots, 0, \pm 1)$$
so there are $2n$ of them.

For $n \ge 3$ we have $2^n \ne 2n$ so the spaces cannot be isometrically isomorphic.